Docker as for deployments on servers
I have a /28 of public IPs.  I do not know much about Docker and would like to see if it would fit my use cases.  I currently use virt-manager/KVM.
Docker docs talk about bridged networks, but it's not clear to me whether they are bridged with the host's real external network interface.  https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/
Can I use docker to deploy:

one or more containers on a single server with bridged, distinct, public internet addresses for each container.
one or more containers on a single server, each with its own 8nnn upstream HTTP server port, so that nginx on the host can send requests for different domains to different containers?


You can configure bridged networks with whatever bridge network configuration you want.

Can I use docker to deploy:
one or more containers on a single server with bridged, distinct, public internet addresses for each container.

Sure. Doesn't sound like a use case for a bridge (it's a bridge with one interface…), but still a bridge.

one or more containers on a single server, each with its own 8nnn upstream HTTP server port, so that nginx on the host can send requests for different domains to different containers?

Sure.

Thanks I'll give it a try.  I would have thought it was a bridge containing the host's eth0 and a separate xxx0 for each container.

macvlan appears to be what I need to make a container work like a VM.  You only really need this if you want to expose ports which aren't readily proxied and/or load balanced.  For http you would just put nginx in front and not need "real" addresses on the containers.
